# I can't boot up my Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have a problem here and that is: 
I installed Ubuntu and encrypted the hard drive when I installed it, after a while, I decided to duel boot Ubuntu and windows 7, I created a partition in my other drive and installed Windows 7.

Now I can't boot up my Ubuntu! I tried boot repair and it doesn't worked for me, then I uninstalled windows 7 and still I have the problem, I guess the problem is encryption?? Please help me I don't know what should I do??

Here is my [summary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3DFHYhCrPv/).

I want to access my files they are really important for me,

Comment: How far do you get into the Bootprocess?
Do you get into the Grubmenu?

Comment: No, it just show me Ubuntu-vg not found, something like that

Comment: Can you make a photo for more details? The more you write details the better we can help you. When you run boot-repair, can you there read your filesystems?

Comment: No I can't, it finished with an error, But I guess my disk is an luks encrypted hard drive, as I searched in gooogle, some said that grub2 doesn't support luks, i'm stressed out, my projects are stored in that drive, is there a way that I change grub to support luks manually??

Comment: I mounted my encrypted hard drive with cryptomount and how to boot that mounted partition??

Comment: Did you mounted the drive in grub or in a live system?

Comment: In grub, but I gives me error: need kernel first something like that, i think I need a full reinstall my grub and kernel because it doesn't recognize my installed kernels, before this problem, when I turned on my laptop just a grub menu opened and showed previous kernels and after that, showed me enter crypto0 password box and after that, my laptop booted up